# Not able to get fields with single quote using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

following is my code:-

```
$cat=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cat']);
$selqry="select * from quizes where category='$cat'";
$selres=mysql_query($selqry) or die(mysql_error());
$questions = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($selres)) {
while($question = mysql_fetch_assoc($selres)) {
  $questions[] = array('post'=>$question);
}
}
else
{
echo "[{\"Result\":\"No questions in this category\"}]";
exit(0);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('questions'=>$questions));
```

Now everything from the table quizes is output in proper json format except the fields that have a single quote in them which are getting output as null..

So am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What fields have a sigle quote in this case? You mean the DB fields or the PHP index names.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is not with the code above, but with the code that inserts the data into the DB in the first place. I suspect you'll find that the fields contain `NULL` in the database itself. Sounds like [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) territory to me...

Comment: BTW just dnt use mysql extension,its going to die in upcoming version.Use mysqli with prepared statements or PDO

Comment: Could you show the output together with a `print_r()` of the `$questions` array? I hope you can narrow it down to just a few entries :)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the replies..I am talking about the column fields of quizes table. BTW I manage the database for this code also and am fixing the null problem by editing the fields that are displaying null directly from the db itself and I am doing this by removing the single quotes in those fields. hope this helps :)

Comment: I am still oh so very confused, can you show us a full example of what you mean in code?

Comment: @user1466594 You shouldn't need to remove the single quotes, I think the ones that are resulting in `null` in the JSON are the ones that are `NULL` in the database. Try selecting a single row that has a single quote in the field and JSON-encoding just that row - you should see the data intact.

Comment: This is since single quote is not actually a special char in JSON only a `"`, `:` and `{}` is. So single quote should, as @DaveRandom said, encode fine.

Comment: Hey guys..actuallt the character is not a single quote, but a backtick character (one that is used as an apostrophe in many places )..any ideas